# Video playback on VideoView disappears after going back from another Activity

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

I have two Activities: one with `VideoView` attached to `MediaPlayer` and the second one.
 I start watching a video in the first Activity, then during playback I start second Activity.
After going back to first Activity I can hear sound but see no picture.

My Video Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <VideoView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/videoView" android:layout_gravity="center" />  
    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:id="@+id/ListView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Do you have any ideas why video doesn't appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've ended up with `MediaPlayer` which is destroyed in `onStop` method and recreated in `onResume` method.

Main drawback of this approach is that after changing orientation `MediaPlayer` has to buffer video again.

I think that the main reason was that reference to `MediaPlayer` was lost. Without reference to `MediaPlayer` I couldn't set `SurfaceView` again, as a Video display.

Answer (score 1):

Might be related to the Activity life cycle.  Do you start playing your video in the onCreate() method? If so, try to move it to onResume(), which gets called when an activity is sent to the background but then brought back again. onCreate() only gets called once, when it's first created.

Comment: I start player in `onTouch` event of `VideoView`. In fact it doesn't stop when another Activity comes to foreground. Although when I go back to Activity with player, video screen goes black.